# How to register service conditional based on top most parent namespace

Tags: c#, design-patterns, interface, inversion-of-control, simple-injector

I have the following classes which I'm having issues with resolving using `SimpleInjector`.

Config Interface

```
Namespace Infrastructure.Base.Interfaces
public interface ILdapConfigService 
{
    ..... 
}
```

Session Interface

```
Namespace Infrastructure.Base.Interfaces
public interface ISessionService 
{
    LdapConnection GetConnection(); 
}
```

Session Implementation

```
Namespace Infrastructure.Base.Services
public class SessionService : ISessionService {

    ILdapConfigService _ldapConfigService;        
    public SessionService (ILdapConfigService ldapConfigService) 
    {
        _ldapConfigService =  ldapConfigService;
    }

    public LdapConnection GetConnection()
    {
        .........
    }
}
```

Config Service Implementation 1

```
namespace Infrastructure.Old.Services
public class OldConfigService : ILdapConfigService 
{
    .... 
}
```

Config Service Implementation 2

```
namespace Infrastructure.New.Services
public class NewConfigService : ILdapConfigService 
{
    .... 
}
```

The idea is to have the `ISessionService` and `SessionService` is in a base project. Then have different projects which implements the `LdapConfigService` witch implements `ILdapConfigService` from the base project.

The different projects will have services which makes use of a repository in the base class too.

I need to know how to register these interfaces, or is it even possible to register it like this?

`Infrastructure.New.Service.SomeService` uses `Infrastructure.Base.Interfaces.IRepository`. 
`Infrastructure.Old.Service.SomeOtherService` uses `Infrastructure.Base.Interfaces.IRepository`.

`Infrastructure.Base.Repositories.Repository` implements `Infrastructure.Base.Interfaces.IRepository`.
`Infrastructure.Base.Repositories.Repository` uses `Infrastructure.Base.Interfaces.ISessionService`.

`Infrastructure.Base.Services.SessionService` implements `Infrastructure.Base.Interfaces.ISessionService`.
`Infrastructure.Base.Services.SessionService` uses `Infrastructure.Base.Interfaces.ILdapConfigService`.

`Infrastructure.New.Services.LdapConfigService` implements `Infrastructure.Base.Interfaces.ILdapConfigService`.

`Infrastructure.Old.Services.LdapConfigService` implements `Infrastructure.Base.Interfaces.ILdapConfigService`.

How can I register this logic with `Simple Injector`. I used `RegisterConditional` but that did not quite work, because the consumer of `ILdapConfigService` sits in base.

```
container.RegisterConditional<
     ILdapConfigService,
     Old.Services.LdapConfigService>(
     c =>  c.Consumer.ImplementationType.Namespace.Contains("Old"));

container.RegisterConditional<
     ILdapConfigService,
     New.Services.LdapConfigService>(
     c =>  c.Consumer.ImplementationType.Namespace.Contains("New"));

container.Register<ISessionService, SessionService>();
container.Register<ILdapRepository, LdapRepository>();
```

Each `LdapConfigService` talks to an `app.config` where all the important information is loaded into.

Base does the whole implementation to `OpenLdap` with exception with the Config with needs to be injected into the `SessionService` so it talks to the right server. Who knew abstraction could get so complicated.

Is my design pattern perhaps flawed?

Comment: So `New.SomeService` should use `New.LdapConfigService` indirectly and `Old.SomeOtherService` should use `Old.LdapConfigService` indirectly?

Comment: Yehp you are correct because each config service is on a unique project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is my design pattern perhaps flawed?

As long as you are sure you aren't violating the Liskov Substitution Principle, I can't find any flaws in it, although this design does make it a bit harder to configure the container.

I think the trick here is to create two `ISessionService` implementations; one for the `New` stuff, an one for the `Old` stuff. This allows you to differentiate based on the types. This is needed, because Simple Injector's `RegisterConditional` has the limitation that only allows you to look at the registration's direct consumer type. You are registering `ILdapConfigService` conditionally, but it always gets injected into `SessionService`. By giving each `ILdpConfigService` its own `ISessionService`, you allow making the condition based on the consumers of `ISessionSerice`.

This limitation of Simple Injector is deliberate and exists to prevent the user from making invalid configurations. For instance, if `SessionService` is registered as singleton, it will be impossible for it to have two different `ILdapConfigServices`.

Since creating two `ISessionService` implementation is a 'configuration trick', you can simply define the second implementation as part of your Composition Root and inherit it from the first. By doing so you can match based on types as shown below:

```
class NewSessionService : SessionService {
    public NewSessionService(ILdabConfigService s) { ... }
}

container.RegisterConditional<ISessionService, SessionService>(
    c => c.Consumer.ImplementationType.Namespace.Contains("Old"));

container.RegisterConditional<ILdabConfigServices, Old.LdapConfigService>(
    c => c.Consumer.ImplementationType == typeof(SessionService));


container.RegisterConditional<ISessionService, NewSessionService>(
    c => c.Consumer.ImplementationType.Namespace.Contains("New"));

container.RegisterConditional<ILdabConfigServices, New.LdapConfigService>(
    c => c.Consumer.ImplementationType == typeof(NewSessionService));
```

Comment: Thank you. I figured that this approach was going to be the easiest way to get it all registered. I did however find a massive flaw in my design, the class libraries won't read from their respective App.config files so I had to chuck everything back into one project. I will post my solution as an answer but yours is just as valid.